Enqueuing in WP/Elementor only when widget is used?
I am in the process of trying to learn how to create plug-ins for Elementor. At the moment I am stuck trying to figure out how you enqueue your JavaScript to only trigger on pages where your widget is in use. As of now, whenever the widget is used any place on the site I can see the .js file in the footer on all pages. Is it at all possible to dequeue it on all non-use pages? Here's my code so far:
<?php
namespace Elementor_Test_Addon;

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

/**
 * Plugin class.
 *
 * The main class that initiates and runs the addon.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
final class Plugin {

    /**
     * Instance
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access private
     * @static
     * @var \Elementor_Test_Addon\Plugin The single instance of the class.
     */
    private static $_instance = null;

    /**
     * Instance
     *
     * Ensures only one instance of the class is loaded or can be loaded.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     * @static
     * @return \Elementor_Test_Addon\Plugin An instance of the class.
     */
    public static function instance() {

        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;

    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Perform some compatibility checks to make sure basic requirements are met.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct() {

        if ( $this->is_compatible() ) {
            add_action( 'elementor/init', [ $this, 'init' ] );
        }

    }

    /**
     * Compatibility Checks
     *
     * Checks whether the site meets the addon requirements.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     */
    public function is_compatible() {

        // Check if Elementor installed and activated
        if ( ! did_action( 'elementor/loaded' ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_notices', [ $this, 'admin_notice_missing_main_plugin' ] );
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    /**
     * Initialize
     *
     * Load the addons functionality only after Elementor is initialized.
     *
     * Fired by `elementor/init` action hook.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     */
    public function init() {

        add_action( 'elementor/widgets/register', [ $this, 'register_widgets' ] );
        add_action( 'elementor/controls/register', [ $this, 'register_controls' ] );
        add_action( 'elementor/frontend/before_register_scripts', [ $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ] );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'enqueue_styles' ] );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ] );

    }

    public function enqueue_styles() {
        // Ensure CSS is loaded only on pages with Elementor
        if ( did_action( 'elementor/loaded' ) ) {
            // Correct the relative path to the CSS file (assuming 'assets' is in the root of the plugin)
            wp_enqueue_style( 'elementor-addon-styles', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../assets/css/style.css' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Enqueue Scripts
     *
     * Use the 'elementor/frontend/before_register_scripts' hook to load scripts before Elementor registers its scripts.
     */
    public function enqueue_scripts() {
        // Debugging: Log message to check if function is running
        error_log('Enqueue Scripts is running.');

        // Register the custom JS file with the correct path
        wp_register_script( 'my-elementor-addon-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../assets/js/app.js', [], '1.0', true );

        // Enqueue the custom JS file
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-elementor-addon-script' );

        // Log if the script is successfully registered and enqueued
        error_log('Custom JS script (app.js) has been enqueued successfully.');
    }
    


    /**
     * Register Widgets
     *
     * Load widgets files and register new Elementor widgets.
     *
     * Fired by `elementor/widgets/register` action hook.
     *
     * @param \Elementor\Widgets_Manager $widgets_manager Elementor widgets manager.
     */
    public function register_widgets( $widgets_manager ) {

        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'widgets/hello-world-widget-1.php';

        $widgets_manager->register( new \Elementor_Test_Addon\Elementor_Hello_World_Widget_1() );

    }

    /**
     * Register Controls
     *
     * Load controls files and register new Elementor controls.
     *
     * Fired by `elementor/controls/register` action hook.
     *
     * @param \Elementor\Controls_Manager $controls_manager Elementor controls manager.
     */
    public function register_controls( $controls_manager ) {
        // Add controls here
    }

}



Try moving the enqueue calls to widgets/hello-world-widget-1.php.

Won't that just do the exact same thing?

Possibly, but worth a try.

Sadly as expected it still enqueues on the entire site this way as well! I do wonder if it is even feasable to do without specifically pinpointing page-id's, which is quite undynamic
